# Error using calc.yhat "incorrect number of subscripts on matrix"

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying to perform a dominance analysis (`calc.yhat`) with the package `yhat`.

```
calc.yhat(lm.out, prec=3)
```

> Error in ds[, i + 1] <- dataMatrix[, ivlist[i]] :
> incorrect number of subscripts on matrix

`lm.out` is defined as

```
Call:
lm(formula = oWE ~ T1DF + T1DC + FA + PI + JC, data = Final_Dataset_mplus)

> Coefficients: 
(Intercept)         T1DF         T1DC           FA  
    2.52380      0.12704      0.15321      0.04018  
         PI           JC  
    0.08618     -0.00488
```

Comment: Hi. Can you try to make a reproducible example please (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This will make it easier for you to get hep. Thanks

Comment: On a first glance, there are a few bugs in `yhat`. Can you rerun your regression on like fifteen rows and then post the output `dput(lm.out)`?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help :-) It turned out I had to install the package 'boot'

Comment: good you got it working. Bit weird though as `boot` is a recommended package so it should arrive with R e.g. there shouldn't be a need to install it.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).